# Column attributes error while importing to MS Sql Server from MUMPS

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm attempting to import data into MSSQL from a MUMPS database. I've configured an ODBC connection to the MUMPS database and can see the expected table structure in the MSSQL Import / Export wizard.

However if I proceed beyond the 'Select Source Tables and Views' screen I get an error,

Cannot load the column attributes from the schema using the current content descriptor

with four column attributes (ORDINAL_POSITION, COLUMN_SIZE, DECIMAL_DIGITS, and COLUMN_SIZE) listed as the error source.

As suggested in the error message I've tried editing the file  ProviderDescriptors.xml (in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\ProviderDescriptors) but to no avail, still get the same error message.

I found and followed this entry on Microsoft Developer
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dataaccesstechnologies/2010/09/09/sql-server-import-export-wizard-fails-while-trying-to-retrieve-the-data-from-pervasive-database/
but no difference.

Can anyone offer any pointers on where I'm going wrong?